# Error while trying to run app. Error: More than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms'

Tags: android, gradle

Please this is not a duplicate as i have tried other solution.

I keep getting error Error: More than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms'

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sensible"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        multiDexEnabled true
    }



    buildTypes {
        release {

        }
    }
}

dependencies {


    compile project(':googleplayserviceslib')

    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.2.1'
}
```

Comment: where is the gradle build file for googleplayserviceslib

Comment: Check build of googleplayserviceslib. some of your dependencies is getting repeated, delete them from your app build.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook sdks will pull in google gms as well, so you'll need to modify it to:

```
compile ('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
}
```

You might also be getting conflicts from

```
compile project(':googleplayserviceslib')
```